# iPhone Wordpress mobile site - custom CSS vs. .htaccess redirect

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I am setting out to build a mobile version of a Wordpress site for the iPhone using iWebKit and the native Apple Safari API; however I am not sure wether to use custom CSS to hide/display certain elements of the page, or to redirect the user to a new site (ex. www.example.com/iphone).

What are the benefits to both? Which do you recommend?

Thanks for any input, and happy Sunday!

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use custom CSS than creating second copy od website which will in the end mean, that you will have to maintain two identical sites (content wise).

Comment: but won't the content update automatically with the mySQL framework that Wordpress uses?

Comment: What MySQL framework? If you are talkign about database, then you can of course have one common, but what are you going to do, when you decide to rename sole site field? (for example)